# C++ builder Android fail to compile App?

Tags: android, c++, c++builder, dynamic-arrays

An Android project is failing to compile within C++Builder 10.1 Berlin Update 2.

The IDE reports these errors:

```
bccaarm command line for "MainU.cpp"
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\bin\bccaarm.exe -cc1 -D _DEBUG -n .\Android\Debug -isysroot 
  C:\Users\MIDO\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\platforms\android-14\arch-arm -idirafter =\usr\include -idirafter 
  C:\Users\MIDO\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\include -idirafter 
  C:\Users\MIDO\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\include -idirafter 
  C:\Users\MIDO\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\libs\armeabi-v7a\include -idirafter 
  C:\Users\MIDO\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\sources\android\native_app_glue -I "D:\L-Development\AUB Projects\AUB 
  Apps\Mobile\AUBE Branch Contacts" -I "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\include\android\fmx" -I "..\..\..\..\Main Library\Units" -I 
  "C:\Users\Ahmed Sayed\Desktop\ActivitiesXE6\ActivitiesXE6" -I "..\..\..\..\Main Library\Units\FMX" -I "..\..\..\..\Main Library\Classes" -I 
  "..\..\..\..\Main Library\Clients\FMX\Frames" -I "D:\L-Development\Main Library\Units\FMX" -I "D:\L-Development\Main Library\Classes" -I 
  "D:\L-Development\Main Library\Clients\FMX\Frames" -I "..\..\..\..\Desktop\AUBE Contacts Test" -isystem "C:\Program Files 
  (x86)\Woll2Woll\FirePower\10.0\include\18.0\Android" -isystem "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\include" -isystem "c:\program files 
  (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\include\android\rtl" -isystem "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\include\android\fmx" -isystem "c:\program 
  files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\include\android\crtl" -isystem C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\hpp\Android -g 
  -fno-limit-debug-info -fborland-extensions -fborland-auto-refcount -nobuiltininc -nostdsysteminc -triple thumbv7-none-linux-androideabi -emit-obj 
  -mconstructor-aliases -pic-level 2 -target-abi aapcs-linux -target-cpu cortex-a8  -nostdinc++ -fdeprecated-macro -fexceptions -fcxx-exceptions 
  -munwind-tables -mstackrealign -fno-spell-checking -main-file-name MainU.cpp -x c++ -std=c++11 -O2 -fmath-errno -tU -o .\Android\Debug\MainU.o 
  -dependency-file .\Android\Debug\MainU.d -MT .\Android\Debug\MainU.o MainU.cpp 
[bccaarm Error] SystemTypes.h(1278): implicit instantiation of undefined template 'System::DynamicArray<unsigned char>'
  sysmac.h(603): template is declared here
[bccaarm Error] SystemTypes.h(1286): implicit instantiation of undefined template 'System::DynamicArray<unsigned char>'
  sysmac.h(603): template is declared here
[bccaarm Error] SystemTypes.h(1292): implicit instantiation of undefined template 'System::DynamicArray<unsigned char>'
  sysmac.h(603): template is declared here
[bccaarm Error] MainU.cpp(1): ICE: Internal compiler error: C0000005 @ 548FD234
```

I don't even use `DynamicArray` anywhere in the project. I am using Windows 10. This was working fine with Windows 7.

The error happens after I add a cpp file to the project. And even if I remove the file from the project, the error remains. It's like the project is corrupted.

This is the error:

[image: Error]

Is this a bug for Android development on Windows 10 or something?

When I build an empty Android project, it compiles fine. But when I only add a file, it produces the `DynamicArray` error above. As you can see, the file code is commented, so there is no reason to give an error at all.

**Resolved:**

Just found a workaround.

The Networking unit that I was adding to the project was originally in a different folder that the project folder so for you to test it you need to move Networking some where else.

Coping the unit files in project directory before adding them fixes the issue for android compilation.

But the problem will exits if I forget and added another unit from a different location. Even after removing that unit the problem remains. It is like the project file has been infected with it.

[Win7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MX3ot.png)

Comment: "*Also i don't use DynamicArray anywhere in the project*" - the error is in a system header, not in your code. `System::TArray` is a typedef of `System::DynamicArray`, and `System::Byte` is a typedef of `unsigned char`. The compiler is complaining that `System::DynamicArray` is not defined yet, and even tells you the header that defines it. Make sure `sysmac.h` is included before `SystemTypes.h`

Comment: do you mean that i should edit SystemTypes.h or just place them both in my main form unit in that order: sysmac.h then SystemTypes.h?

Comment: Do *NOT* edit SystemTypes.h!!!  Just make sure you include the right headers, in the right order.

Comment: I am sorry but could someone tell me exactly what should i do and where?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I tried both Berlin update 2 and Tokyo Release 1 and both produces the same compiling error. This worked fine in Win 7 so it might be either Windows 10, Win 10 SDK or the Android API version.

Comment: @AhmedSayed this has nothing to do with the OS, or the Win32 SDK

Comment: @RemyLebeau then how come it worked on another machine with windows 7 and not with windows 10? I need to fix this i have a deadline at work and i can't postpone it at all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hey guys has any one experienced anything like this before? please a little help here I am stuck?

Answer (score 0):

1. This compile error should be easy to resolve:

   PROBLEM:

   `[bccaarm Error] SystemTypes.h(1278): implicit instantiation of undefined template 'System::DynamicArray<unsigned char>'
   sysmac.h(603): template is declared here`

   SOLUTION:

   `#include <sysmac.h>`

   `#include <SystemTypes.h>`

In other words, include "sysmac.h" before "SystemTypes.h"

2. I understand that you THINK it works on Win7, but not on Win10 ... but that's probably just a "coincidence".  Maybe you have a different SDK and/or compiler version, maybe it was installed differently ... there are a million possibilities.  But it's unlikely the problem is "win7" vs. "win10" per se...
3. In your example, you commented out every line in "Networking.h".  Why??? In general, you should never NEVER edit system headers.
4. You might want to consider doing a "clean" of your project, and rebuilding from scratch.
5. You might even want to consider uninstalling and reinstalling C++ Builder and your Android SDK.  Or installing it on a different PC.

I hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks for the reply but where exactly do you want me to include these headers:#include <sysmac.h>,#include <SystemTypes.h> in Main form unit or project source?

Comment: I commented every line in "Networking.h" to see if there was a line of code that generates the error because i have other files added to the project and they don't cause this problem